# when do you need to use a power distribution block in your schematic?

Tags: power

So i am fairly new to industrial automation however i have noticed a trend in quite a few schematics which have more than one 3 phase motor involved and the power distribution block is always there. So am i safe to say that when you have more then one motor involved you need a power distribution block?

Comment: an ideal 0 Ohm voltage source implies a very low ESR and ESL from a  power block to drive low DCR motors.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't need a power distribution block in systems which has more than one 3-phase motor. A power distribution block helps you to create more efficient wiring.

When you use a distribution block, it is no longer necessary to switch every device in the control circuit back to the power source. This can be done with the help of one large wire on the input side and several smaller wires on the output to the downstream devices. All this makes the whole look more professional and better.